# Strange crashes on startup inside CCSprite's -draw method

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, crash, cocos2d-iphone

I got an iPhone application using Cocos2d (version: `#define COCOS2D_VERSION 0x00010000`). It works ok on my iPad and iPhone, as well as on various iPhones I tested it on.

But on one (3G) it keeps crashing every time during initialization - the crash log shows the problem in `CCSprite.m` file, in the `-draw` method - in this line:

```
// tex coords
diff = offsetof( ccV3F_C4B_T2F, texCoords);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, kQuadSize, (void*)(offset + diff)); // This line crashes
```

The crashlog shows the following:

```
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000004
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MBXGLEngine                     0x302554e8 0x30229000 + 181480
1   MBXGLEngine                     0x30256980 0x30229000 + 186752
2   MBXGLEngine                     0x3022ca80 0x30229000 + 14976
3   MBXGLEngine                     0x30252580 0x30229000 + 169344
4   S100                            0x000342d8 -[CCSprite draw] (CCSprite.m:606)
5   S100                            0x00023e74 -[CCNode visit] (CCNode.m:550)
6   S100                            0x00023e14 -[CCNode visit] (CCNode.m:535)
7   S100                            0x00023e50 -[CCNode visit] (CCNode.m:545)
8   S100                            0x00048500 -[CCDirectorIOS drawScene] (CCDirectorIOS.m:169)
9   Foundation                      0x35168eda 0x35151000 + 98010
10  Foundation                      0x35168d5e 0x35151000 + 97630
11  S100                            0x0004ad38 -[EAGLView layoutSubviews] (EAGLView.m:214)
```

Comment: I have this problem too... did you find a solution?

Comment: That issue seemed to stop ocuring when I commented out the 'remove flicker' code from my App Delegate - one with buffers swapping. Maybe this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

What's the size of the texture? On older device it cannot be more than 1024x1024.